# google calendar api .net

Tags: .net, google-calendar-api

I'm using google api 2.0 for .net. I use this code to create a new calendar:

```
CalendarEntry calendar = new CalendarEntry();
calendar.Title.Text = "Little League Schedule";
calendar.Summary.Text = "This calendar contains the practice schedule and game times.";
calendar.TimeZone =  "America/Los_Angeles";
calendar.Hidden = false;
calendar.Color = "#2952A3";
calendar.Location = new Where("", "", "Oakland");

Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/owncalendars/full");
CalendarEntry createdCalendar = (CalendarEntry) service.Insert(postUri, calendar);
```

but, on execution, return the error:

**Execution of request failed**

at the line

CalendarEntry createdCalendar = (CalendarEntry) service.Insert(postUri, calendar);

However, if I connect to google calendar with the browser, the new calendar is created.

Also, I use this code to retriving all calendars and it's works

```
CalendarQuery query = new CalendarQuery();
query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/allcalendars/full");
CalendarFeed resultFeed = (CalendarFeed) service.Query(query);
```

Any suggestions?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better you start using .net calendar API V3 since V2 is obsolete so is OAuth 1.0